# Create a zip file for NetBeans project in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, netbeans

I would like to create a zip file for my NetBeans project which has a database named hoteldb. The steps which I know are:

1)Start the SQL server (type mysqld --standalone in a command window)

2)In a new command window type: mysqldump hoteldb -u root

3)Assuming everything worked correctly in step 2(the result must be something like the following code) I should now give the command: mysqldump hoteldb -u root > dump.sql

I am using MySql5.5 and these steps are not working. Is something missing or what I must change in these lines of code?

The output of step 2 should be something like:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost Database: hoteldb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 5.0.51b-community
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
--
-- Table structure for table `reservation`
--
......
--
-- Dumping data for table `reservation`
--
......
--
-- Table structure for table `room`
--
......
--
-- Dumping data for table `room`
--
......
/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;
-- Dump completed on 2010-11-19 11:29:31
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of you mysqldump command looks a little incorrect.

It should read:

```
mysqldump -u root -p<your_password> hoteldb > dump.sql;
```

You can then zip up the resulting dump.sql file.

Also, it could be that mysqld is not starting correctly? Check this by starting it up as you've described and then trying to login as root.